# Prolog generating all possible operation for given list

Tags: list, prolog, operators, combinations, permutation

Hello I am facing a problem. Let's say I have 3 operations(+,-,*).
I would like to generate variable that contains all possible expressions for given list of arguments using those 3 operators.

`my_problem([1,2],X)` would return

```
X=1-2
X=1*2
X=1+2
```

`my_problem([1,2,3],X)` would return

```
X=1+2+3  X=1-2-3
X=1+2-3  X=1+2*3 
X=1-2+3  ...
```

and so on.

I know that i can build expression using this predicates.

```
args_expr(Arg1,Arg2,Arg1 + Arg2).
args_expr(Arg1,Arg2,Arg1 - Arg2).
args_expr(Arg1,Arg2,Arg1 * Arg2).
```

Is there any clever way to generete this variable? I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: By *all possible expressions* do you just mean all expressions that use each value you give exactly once? And in cases where associativity makes a difference, are you wanting all of the possibilities (e.g., `X=1+2*3`, `X=(1+2)*3`, `X=1*2+3`, `X=1*(2+3)`, etc)? It's a little unclear exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the so called "univ" operator, `=..`, to build expressions:

```
?- Expr =.. [+, A, B].
Expr = A+B.
```

And you can enumerate the operations you have:

```
op(+). op(-). op(*).
```

Then:

```
?- op(Op), Expr =.. [Op, A, B].
Op =  (+),
Expr = A+B ;
Op =  (-),
Expr = A-B ;
Op =  (*),
Expr = A*B.
```

Or maybe:

```
?- op(Op1), op(Op2), E =.. [Op1, A, E0], E0 =.. [Op2, B, C].
```

From here to what you need is just figuring out how to do this for lists of arbitrary number of elements (not just two or three).

**Hint**: If you figure out how to define `expr/3`, you can do:

```
?- foldl(expr, [B,C], A, E).
E = C+ (B+A) ;
E = C- (B+A) ;
E = C* (B+A) ;
E = C+ (B-A) ;
E = C- (B-A) ;
E = C* (B-A) ;
E = C+B*A ;
E = C-B*A ;
E = C* (B*A).
```

Of course, the second argument to `foldl` can be a list of arbitrary length.